# Xamarin - How to layer View on top of another, like Keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin

I have a custom UI I want to show like the keyboard when a user clicks a part of the screen. I've seen examples however they reference methods off of UIView which don't seem to exist (maybe it's because I have the Starter license?)  for example UIView.beginAnimations  isn't there.

Does anyone have a Xamarin (i.e. MonoTouch) example?

I want my UI piece to show, and to scroll the existing view so that the field is properly visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UITextView` and `UITextField` have `inputView` property, which allows you to achieve exactly what you need. Setup the view, set it as their input view, and once the user makes a text view or a text field first responder, your view will appear. iOS7 has `UIInputView` class, which you can subclass, to achieve a similar background view as the keyboard.

Comment: Can I create a regular ViewController and use its view for the InputView (allowing me to do this visually in XCode) or do I have to do this entirely by code?

Comment: @DrissZouak If you use a XIB file, you basically define a view only, not a view controller, whereas a storyboard defines view controllers. It is preferable to subclass a view, but it is possible to use the view controller's view as the input view, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create your view and place it outside the visible view. When you want to show it, you just move it into the visible area. That way you can also add the animation.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *yourHiddenViewYConstraint;

- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [self.view addSubView:yourHiddenView];
    [yourHiddenView setHidden:YES];
    UIView *selfView = self.view
    yourHiddenView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    // add your needed constraints, other than the one below
    yourHiddenViewYConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yourHiddenView
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                     relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                        toItem:selfView
                                                     attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                    multiplier:1.0
                                                      constant:0];
    [selfView addConstraint:yourHiddenViewYConstraint];
    yourHiddenViewYConstraint.constant += self.view.frame.size.height;
}
```

To show it when needed:

```
- (void)showView
{
    [yourHiddenView setHidden:NO];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
        [self changeConstraint:yourHiddenViewYConstraint withConstant:-self.view.frame.size.height];
    });
}

- (void)changeConstraint:(NSLayoutConstraint *)constraint withConstant:(CGFloat)constant
{
    constraint.constant += constant;

    void (^anim)(void) = ^{
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    };

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:anim completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: This would create an ambiguous layout. You have not provided enough constraints for the hidden view. Also, completely over the top - too complicated for the task at hand.

Comment: Ignores my point regarding Xamarin and C#, I was having trouble getting examples that worked in Xamarin.